# Vectorised Function in numjac MatLab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to solve a large DAE system, coupled with the equations to calculate the sensitivity of the variables to a parameter. My problem is the jacobian of the entire system, its calculation is pretty slow and I would like to speed it up.

I am using `numjac`, in this form:

```
[Jx,FAC,G] = numjac(@(t,y)MODEL(t,y,X),tt,yy,dydt,jac_tol,FAC,0,JPat,G);
```

I want to vectorize the code, but I can't seem to get what [this](http://www.ligo-wa.caltech.edu/~cheryl.vorvick/etmx2007/OldStuffFromPCLaptop/MATLAB6p1/toolbox/matlab/funfun/numjac.m) means. As far as I understood my code is already vectorized! `t`,`y`,`X` go in and I get a column vector of `dy(i)/dt`, or `F(t,y(i))`. But if I say that my function is vectorized, I get an error:

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in numjac (line 192)
Fdiff = Fdel - Fty(:,ones(1,ng));
```

How can I properly vectorize it?

Comment: Try `bsxfun(@minus,Fdel,Fty)` maybe, but I am suggesting this without knowing about the input sizes, so give it a try.

Comment: @Divakar are you saying I should modify the `numjac` ?

Comment: Well that function code is huge! So, I have no idea if you should look to vectorize it or not. I was only trying to address that error in  `Fdiff = Fdel - Fty(:,ones(1,ng));` wherever it is!

Comment: But `numjac` is given in Matlab, and I'd rather not touch it...